# Is SciPy 0.19.0 available for download to be used for legacy code

Tags: python, scipy

Can SciPy 0.19.0 be downloaded for legacy code? When using `pip-install` with python 2.7.13, installation is unsuccessful with error code 1.

SciPy 0.19.0 to install correctly from:

```
python -m pip install -v "scipy==0.19.0"
```

When using python 2.7.13 and pip version 20.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

[Conda forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scipy) has Scipy 0.19 for Python 2.7, and also for 3.5 and 3.6:

```
➜ conda search "scipy==0.19.0"
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
scipy                         0.19.0 np111py27_blas_openblas_200  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np111py27_blas_openblas_201  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np111py27_blas_openblas_202  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np111py35_blas_openblas_200  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np111py35_blas_openblas_201  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np111py35_blas_openblas_202  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np111py36_blas_openblas_200  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np111py36_blas_openblas_201  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np111py36_blas_openblas_202  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np112py27_blas_openblas_200  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np112py27_blas_openblas_201  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np112py27_blas_openblas_202  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np112py35_blas_openblas_200  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np112py35_blas_openblas_201  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np112py35_blas_openblas_202  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np112py36_blas_openblas_200  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np112py36_blas_openblas_201  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np112py36_blas_openblas_202  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np113py27_blas_openblas_202  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np113py35_blas_openblas_202  conda-forge
scipy                         0.19.0 np113py36_blas_openblas_202  conda-forge
```

You can install it in a new environment with:

```
conda create -n my_env -c conda-forge "python<3" "scipy==0.19.0"
```